# Dealing with the `this` keyword in named methods

Tags: jquery

A pretty simple problem, but it's one I want to get your opinion on:

```
function return_this_normal(){
//    console.log($(this));
     $(this).css('color','green');

}

$('.normal').mouseover( function(){
//        console.log($(this));
        $(this).css('color','red');
        return_this_normal()
   }
);
```

Now, the above script turns the '.normal' div's text red on hover. You might expect it to turn it to green, because it calls `return_this_normal` after it turns the text red and `return_this_normal` changes the css of `this` to green.

However, it doesn't because `this` in `return_this_normal` returns not the element, but the actual function itself how exists in the browser's memory ( or something like that ). Suffice to say, updating the css of this function as it were does nothing at all.

Now to get around this trouble, we could simple pass the `.normal` element to the `return_this_normal()` function as a parameter, but I'm just wondering if there is a standardized way to do this in jquery as passing an element to a named function seems like pretty common functionality  .

http://jsfiddle.net/Ea5Rh/3/

Comment: it is because there is no execution context specified for the method `return_this_normal` - see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nMp9w/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a function to jQuery, so you can run `$(element).my_function()` then you can add it to the `$.fn` object. In that function, `this` is set as expected.

```
$.fn.return_this_normal = function(){
     return this.css('color','green');       
}

$('.normal').mouseover( function(){
        $(this).css('color','red');
        $(this).return_this_normal();
   }
);
```

Note I am returning from the function to support jQuery's chaining syntax.

Otherwise you should pass `this` as an argument to your function, which is a perfectly normal thing to do if the function isn't a member of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Pass this to `return_this_normal` as this is only available in handler of mouseover

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ea5Rh/4/)**

```
/* Normal */
function return_this_normal(ob){
   // console.log($(this));
     $(ob).css('color','green');

}

$('.normal').mouseover( function(){
//        console.log($(this));
        $(this).css('color','red');
        return_this_normal(this)
   }
);
```

You can also pass the this using .call()

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ea5Rh/5/)**

```
/* Normal */
function return_this_normal(){
    console.log($(this));
     $(this).css('color','green');

}

$('.normal').mouseover( function(){
//        console.log($(this));
        $(this).css('color','red');
        return_this_normal.call(this)
   }
);
```